# How to connect to local sql server database from dockerized python app

Tags: python, sql-server, docker

I am trying to connect to a long-running SQL server database on my local machine from a dockerized python container, but I keep getting the error below. I will add all relevant code as well. I can confirm,m the username and password are both correct(I have verified 10+ times and set up a new account on the server and database with full rights as well).

I have scoured stack overflow and articles for the last day, but none have given me anything different, so I am hoping someone here will have some info that will point me in the right direction. Please let me know if you need any more info.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myusername'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN echo "[FreeTDS]\n\
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver\n\
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so\n\
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install unixodbc -y \
 && apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y \
 && apt-get install freetds-dev -y \
 && apt-get install freetds-bin -y \
 && apt-get install tdsodbc -y \
 && apt-get install --reinstall build-essential -y

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org pyodbc==4.0.26 

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY src/. .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

And here is main.py

```
import pyodbc

try:
  sql_connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={FreeTDS};'
                                  'Server=host.docker.internal,1433;'
                                  'Database=mydatabasename;' 
                                  'UID=myusername;'
                                  'PWD=mypassword')
  sql_cursor = sql_connection.cursor()
  sql_cursor.execute("Select @@version")

  print(sql_cursor.fetchone())
finally:
  sql_cursor.close()
  sql_connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

i would start with first trying to connect to this DB from inside the running docker container (via docker exec) using SQL client (psql, mysql-client whatever the DB you have) and connfirm you can do it. If not obviously smth on DB level doesn't allow the connection possibly only 127.0.0.1 is allowed in the DB settings

Comment: This helped point me in the right direction. I used docker exec -it -H host.docker.internal -L 

That gave me info, such as the instance name and version of SQL server I was hitting., 

This differed from the "server" I had set the account up on in SSMS on my local machine. 

So today I learned I can have multiple instances locally. So I created my user on the other "instance" and it let me log in as expected. 

Thank you for this nudge.